# Getting text from website from a pandas python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a list of reaction names from which I want to make a Search in ModelSeed (basically "https://modelseed.org/biochem/reactions/" + reaction name). Then I want to know the KEGG pathway for the given name.

For instance, for the reaction "rxn00020", the function would go to https://modelseed.org/biochem/reactions/rxn00020 and from there give me "KEGG: rn00500 (Starch and sucrose metabolism)". I tried following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962006/using-python-to-ask-a-web-page-to-run-a-search) but didn't manage to get anything done... Can you help me?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page contents are loaded dynamically, so you have to use `selenium` in order to scrape them. Here is how you do it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

urls = ['https://modelseed.org/biochem/reactions/rxn00020'] #List of all your urls

for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(1.5)
    kegg = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ng-binding')[-2]
    print(kegg.text)
```

Output:

```
KEGG: rn00500 (Starch and sucrose metabolism)
```

Answer (score 0):

Res contains what u want. Take a look to Network Tab from your Web Inspector.

The data you want, transits through XHR requests.

```
import requests as rq

reaction_names = ["rxn00020", ]
res = {}
base_url = "https://modelseed.org/solr/reactions/select?wt=json&q=id:"

for reac_name in reaction_names:
    resp = rq.get(base_url + reac_name).json()
    res[reac_name] = resp['response']['docs'][0]['pathways']
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the help but I'm afraid it did not work for me. Anyway, the problem is solved!